# Create dynamic associative array in php in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have loop like this

```
foreach($this->input->post('users') as $value)
        {
            foreach($this->input->post('group_name') as $v)
            {
                echo $value.','.$v.'<br>';

            }
        }
```

And its ouput is

```
17,5
17,6
18,5
18,6
19,5
19,6
20,5
20,6
```

Now i want to create an associative array like this using the above values.

```
array(
        array(
                'user_id' => 17,
                'group_id' => 15
        ),
       ....
       ....
      array(
                'user_id' => 20,
                'group_id' => 6
        )

)
```

How can i do that 
I've tried this in foreach loop but it will print two separate arrays.

```
            $temp['user_id'][]=$v;
            $temp['group_id'][]=$value;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is append array with respective values.

```
$result = [];
foreach($this->input->post('users') as $value)
{
        foreach($this->input->post('group_name') as $v)
        {
                $result[] = ['user_id' => $value, 'group_id' => $v];
        }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: But i don't want the keys

Comment: `Arrays` stores values on keys, see docs : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Please look at the sample output array in my question

Comment: Yes I did, they also have keys (numeric keys)

Comment: No there is no keys

Comment: when you don't define key `[]` it will take incremental numeric keys, starting from 0... do `print_r($array);` and check yourself.

Comment: Sorry got it:) bro

Answer (score 1):

This loop should help you out.

```
$resultArray = [];
foreach($this->input->post('users') as $value) {
    foreach($this->input->post('group_name') as $v) {
        $resultArray[] = array(
            'user_id' => $value,
            'group_id' => $v,
        );
    }
}

var_dump($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you just have to append/push the child array into main array.

**Like this,**

```
$main_array=array();
foreach($this->input->post('users') as $value)
        {
            foreach($this->input->post('group_name') as $v)
            {
                $group_array=array();
                $group_array["group_id"]=$v;
                $group_array["user_id"]=$value;
                $main_array[]=$group_array;
                //echo $value.','.$v.'<br>';
            }
        }
print_r($group_array);
```

You may also use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to push child array into main array.

Syntax for that would be,

```
array_push($main_array, $child_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this

```
$temp = array();
foreach($this->input->post('users') as $key=>$value)
    {
        foreach($this->input->post('group_name') as $v)
        {
            $temp[$key]['user_id']=$v;

            $temp[$key]['group_id']=$value;

        }
    }

print_r($temp);
```